# AIX shell script compiler

Tags: shell, scripting

I know it sounds strange, but is there a good tool that compiles a shell (.sh) script into a executable format? I want to protect the script in such a way it will not be modified by someone.

Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: i found 1 on this link (http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/)   but i can't find a way how can i install the shc-3.8.9.tgz file, my main concern is that i want to secure the code for version control purpose.

Comment: I have seen such things before, they do not "compile" anything.  Basically, these things generate a wrapper program reading in the program from the data within the single file and using a subshell for each coded command.  It's not really worth the effort and can cause substantial loss of speed as well as compatibility between system releases, and other linux/unix based systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent MODIFICATION by setting the .sh file(s) to have READ/EXECUTE access to everybody.  (i.e. chmod 555 filename.sh) Even then, the owner and root (and anybody with WRITE access to the directory) will always be able to make modifications to the .sh file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `chattr +i <script name>`, set the script owner as root, and give it read / execute permissions.

Once this flag is set to the script, only root will be able to edit it (after running `chattr -i <script name>` )

More info can be found here: http://computernetworkingnotes.com/managing-file-system-security/chattr.html